# How do I limit the number of results I get?

Tags: php

I already have a limit 20. But how do I also limit the page numbers?

[image: http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/2299/28288114.png]

I'm trying to display the first 5 pages than have a ...[$lastpage]

So it would display like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... 64
```

How would I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy someone else's logic.  For instance: http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter when you loop through printing each page number....limit it to 5 or whatever number. Use an if statement to print only if the counter is >= 5 or the last page number.